# How to retrieve a result set from a raw query as an array instead of an object in Laravel 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

By default, Laravel's raw query methods return results as arrays of stdClass objects:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => admin
            [password] => admin123
            [email] => admin@admin.com
            [created_at] => 2012-12-06 18:57:19
            [updated_at] => 2012-12-06 00:00:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [username] => userna
            [password] => user
            [email] => user@gmail.com
            [created_at] => 2012-12-06 00:00:00
            [updated_at] => 2012-12-05 00:00:00
        )
)
```

The question is how to have Laravel return an array of Arrays instead:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [username] => admin
                [password] => admin123
                [email] => admin@admin.com
                [created_at] => 2012-12-06 18:57:19
                [updated_at] => 2012-12-06 00:00:00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [username] => userna
                [password] => user
                [email] => user@gmail.com
                [created_at] => 2012-12-06 00:00:00
                [updated_at] => 2012-12-05 00:00:00
            )
    )
```

Comment: Please provide your code that result in this

Comment: This made perfect sense to me, I'm trying to learn Laravel and ran into this roadblock. It's a real and valid question - wondering if the people that say it isn't have any experience with this framework?

Comment: Why the hell was this closed? People need to get over themselves.

Comment: Have a better answer to add, please reopen

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Original answer for Laravel 3

Eloquent has a method `to_array()`

From docs:

> The to_array method will automatically grab all of the attributes on
>   your model, as well as any loaded relationships.

```
$user = User::find($id);

return Response::json($user->to_array());
```

or

```
return Response::eloquent($user);
```

If you are using fluent, you can do as Sinan suggested and change the global configuration to return an associative array rather than objects.

Alternatively, you can convert an object to and from JSON to convert it to an array although the global option would be preferable in most cases. You can use the following in projects where you prefer objects normally but in certain edge cases need an array. This method will not play well with Eloquent, use the methods above in that case.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('name', '=', 'david')->get();

return array_map(function($val)
{
    return json_decode(json_encode($val), true)
}, $users);
```

Another option would be to temporarily change the runtime configuration

```
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

## For Laravel ~4

In Laravel 4 onwards, all method names conform to PSR-2 standards.

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

return Response::json($user->toArray());

// In Laravel 5 onward the functions are preferred to facades.
return response()->json($user->toArray());
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception
Message:

Call to undefined method stdClass::to_array()

Comment: This is for Laravel 3.x, `to_array()` is a method of Eloquent. Also in the docs http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent. Could you share some of your code for us to see where the problem lies?

Comment: Does Fluent have an equivalent of `to_array()`?

Comment: His problem is: ``$arrOfObjects = DB::connection()->query('SELECT * from `table` LIMIT 0, 3');`` Which *does* return an array of objects. Sinan answered it. The stdClass is determined in the laravel/database/connection.php file based on the config.

Comment: @Sinan is correct. Simply modify the config file and move on with your project. Be careful though if your app is a workflow since not all users will have this setting. If it's just for you then this works fine.

Comment: in laravel 4, this function not found

Comment: That's beause this answer is for laravel 3. Laravel 4 is `toArray()`

Answer (score 36):

You may also get all the result always as array by changing

application/config/database.php

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
```

on line 31 to

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
```

Comment: but how to do it dynamically in the code? I only want to fetch as Array for one DB connection. I have this connection `$sqlserv_connection = DB::connection($this->getSqlServerConnectionName());` I want something like `$sqlserv_connection->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` I know this doesn't exist but how can I achieve this?

Comment: Just want to point out the 'fetch' setting is not connection specific and is at the top of database.php. Somehow I inferred it was connection specific and added it to each connection, which has no effect. Hopefully that helps some  other misguided soul.

Comment: Not sure about 4 or 3, but in Laravel 5, you can make a query:
`$query = DB::table('companies')->where('status', 'active');`
then set this before you run it
`DB::connection()->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
then get the result
`$result = $query->get()->toArray();`
and `$result` will be an array of arrays

Comment: @PhillipHarrington this seems to have been removed :( `Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setFetchMode()`

Comment: @JeffPuckett Looks like it was dropped in 5.4 per this issue:  https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17728

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if laravel has in built function for returning results as array but if not you can use this snippet:

Where `$data` is your returned array of objects

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode((array) $data), true);
```

Comment: @ramesh No problem, there is another answer here that may be of more use as it is using laravel methods see DavidBarker answer

Comment: This is a very bad practice, since you're both encoding it and then decoding it. This will result in the exact same outcome: `$data = (array) $data;`

Comment: @nerdklers It wont because `$data` is already an array it won't change the inner objects to an array, I did try that method myself before posting this unruly workaround :)