# Laravel numeric array in select results

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, lumen

I'm using Lumen to set up a microservice for polling a database frequently and distribute the dataset through a wamp router to multiple clients. The database query is stored in a stored procedure, that's why i do the following in my controller:

```
$result = DB::select($query);

return $result;
```

The return gives the following dataset:

```
[
    {
        "0": "012345",
        "1": "Moby Dick",
        "2": "Herman Melville",
        "3": "Hardcover",
        "isbn": "012345",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "type": "Hardcover"
    },
    {
        "0": "123456",
        "1": "Laravel: Code Bright",
        "2": "Dayle Rees",
        "3": "Ebook",
        "isbn": "123456",
        "title": "Laravel: Code Bright",
        "author": "Dayle Rees",
        "type": "Ebook"
    },
    {
        "0": "234567",
        "1": "Easy Laravel 5",
        "2": "W.J. Gilmore",
        "3": "Ebook",
        "isbn": "234567",
        "title": "Easy Laravel 5",
        "author": "W.J. Gilmore",
        "type": "Ebook"
    }
]
```

I want to remove the numeric key-value pairs prepending the associative key-value pairs. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: things I tried:

```
$result = DB::select($query)->get(); // Gives: Call to a member function get() on array. For obvious reasons
```

A dirty hack like Matei stated: Looping through the array and removing the KVP where the key is numeric. Which works, but I think the Laravel/Lumen framework offers cleaner solutions, which I am not able to find.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you tried. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: @JamieSterling, I updated my question. Not looking for a free coding service. I already get it working on a dirty way like Matei stated, but i'm aiming for clean code, and getting the most out of the laravel/lumen framework. So the question is related to that framework.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/database.php` you can change `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,` to `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,`

**or**

You can use `array_reduce` and `array_filter` like:

```
$result = json_decode(DB::select($query), true);

$result = array_reduce($result, function ($result, $item) {
     $result[] = array_filter($result, function ($key) {
         return !is_numeric($key);
     }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)

     return $result;
}, array());

return json_encode($result);
```

**NOTE**: If the DB stmt is returning an array, rather than a json encoded string, then you must remove the `json_decode` and `json_encode` functions calls.

Comment: Thanks Matei! I got some similar code working, but I'm actually looking for the 'laravel' way, to do this.

Comment: Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746199/how-to-retrieve-a-result-set-from-a-raw-query-as-an-array-instead-of-an-object-i

Comment: I've updated my answer also.. please check if that is what you need